# source javascript file in jsp with spring mvc <3.0.4

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I know this has been asked, but that didn't solve my problem and have tried many things unsuccessfully:

My spring webapp project directory is pretty standard and looks like:

```
/webapp/js/* eg.  /webapp/js/query.jeditable.js
/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/*
/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml+
/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml - dispatcher servlet config
/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml - spring security config
```

I am trying to source a javascript file in js from jsp url, which is also filtered through spring security url matcher.
Here is my web.xml:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
    <display-name>Welcome to projectBananaStand</display-name>
    <description>
            Welcome to 'projectBananaStand' Add Event Test
    </description>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>jmxLogEnabled</param-name>      
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

  <servlet>  
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
 </servlet>  

 <servlet-mapping>  
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
  <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>


 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>


    <listener>
            <listener-class>com.jpmorgan.tyger.listeners.JMXLog4JContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>registerName</param-name>       
        <param-value>projectBananaStand</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


        <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/custError.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <distributable />

</web-app>
```

This is my jsp code trying to source js file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<!-- editable datatables -->
<script src="/js/jquery.jeditable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/addEvent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">



 <context:annotation-config />  
 <!-- declaring base package  -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.banana.controller" />


<mvc:annotation-driven/>


 <!-- adding view resolver to show jsp's on browser -->
 <bean id="viewResolver"  
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix">
  <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value></property>

  <property name="suffix">
  <value>.jsp</value>
  </property>
 </bean>  

     <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>


  </beans>
```

All app level beans and spring security related configuration has been defined in applicationContext.xml and added via contextListener

I cannot use

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />
```

as I am using Spring 3.0.3 and don't want to upgrade whole framework.

I tried using just the xmlns definition for spring mvc 3.1 and that still caused the error - mvc:resource declaration not found.

I tried mapping a default servlet with url patterns

```
*.js, /js/**, and /somethingelse/*
```

and they broke the spring security default login page loading. Resource not found error for the spring security login page.

Tried different tags inside the jsp file including

```
source="<c:url value="something" />"
```

Please help, how can I include the javascript files in jsp without `mvc:resource mapping`or use `mvc:resource mapping` without changing all spring framework version and just using different 
`xmlns schemaLocation`and not bring spring security with `default servlet`

Is there a way to include the files without treating them as urls? What am I doing wrong?
 Help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent much time battling this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep your js folder into /WEB-INF/jsp/ folder it may be work i did not tried.

Comment: contents of /WEB-INF/ are not accessible to the browser I believe